# Server IP Address Showing In _SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]. Is this OK?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I am currently setting up a nginx proxy for apache2 in digital ocean. I am not really an Admin Person but I followed this tutorial https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-as-a-web-server-and-reverse-proxy-for-apache-on-one-ubuntu-14-04-droplet. He said that "The REMOTE_ADDR variable will now also be that of your local computer's public IP address",

Here is my rpaf.conf

`<IfModule mod_rpaf.c>
        RPAF_Enable             On
        RPAF_Header             X-Real-Ip
        RPAF_ProxyIPs           127.0.0.1 10.0.0.0/24
        RPAF_SetHostName        On
        RPAF_SetHTTPS           On
        RPAF_SetPort            On
</IfModule>`

However, It's the server IP address showing on REMOTE_ADDR. Is this OK?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the server's address to `RPAF_ProxyIPs`.

The page you linked contains an example configuration which redirects every request to the server's external IP address. I'm talking about this one:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name foobar.net www.foobar.net test.io www.test.io;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://111.111.111.111:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
  }
}
```

Here, the `111.111.111.111` address is supposed to be the server's real IP address. If you changed that to your server's address, Apache will see the connection originated from the server's external interface (and pointing to the very same interface). For this, the RPAF's `ProxyIPs` setting should contain the server's external address, since that is the one supplying the proxy information.